# Truncate temp table Vs Drop temp table Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

There are two ways to check the existence of `temp table` and recreate it

1.

```
IF Object_id('TEMPDB..#temp') IS NOT NULL
  TRUNCATE TABLE #temp
ELSE
  CREATE TABLE #temp
    (
       id INT
    )
```

2.

```
IF Object_id('TEMPDB..#temp') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #temp

  CREATE TABLE #temp
    (
       id INT
    )
```

is there any advantage of using one over the another

Comment: I believe that the two ways you provided are produces different result.

Comment: yes one is using Truncate another one is using drop but both the queries are intended to do the same thing

Comment: i think your 2nd case is without the `ELSE`

Comment: I agree with @Horia here. That's why I think it's different. Your 2nd case would not recreate the table after the `DROP`.

Comment: Assuming you meant to recreate the table after dropping it.. Anyway, if you don't drop the table, there's the possibility that it exists with a different schema than you want, because a previous query also used `#temp` for something else.

Comment: @FelixPamittan - sorry guys. Updated

Comment: @Horia - yep updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is table called `temp` `TRUNCATE` it otherwise create new table.

```
IF Object_id('temp') IS NOT NULL
  TRUNCATE TABLE temp
ELSE
   CREATE TABLE temp
    (
       id INT
    );
```

There is possibility that original table has different schema than in `ELSE` statement you will end with bad structure.

```
CREATE TABLE temp(col VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('a');

IF Object_id('temp') IS NOT NULL
  TRUNCATE TABLE temp
ELSE
    CREATE TABLE temp
    (
       id INT
    );

INSERT INTO temp VALUES (1);
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/87a25/1/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════╗
║ col ║
╠═════╣
║   1 ║
╚═════╝
```

---

If there is table called `temp` drop it. Then recreate it.

```
IF Object_id('TEMPDB..#temp') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp
(
       id INT
);
```

In this example you are always sure that you get structure defined in `CREATE` statement.

```
CREATE TABLE temp(col VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO temp VALUES ('a');

IF Object_id('temp') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE temp

CREATE TABLE temp
(
       id INT
)    

INSERT INTO temp
VALUES (1);
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/26772/1/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════╗
║ id ║
╠════╣
║  1 ║
╚════╝
```

---

If table does not exist both method return the same structure:

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo_3`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6e18d/1/0)**</kbd>
<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo_4`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b6de9/1/0)**</kbd>

Comment: Yeah you are right never thought about structure change..:)